# Tour page and representation of IPS

Tags: discussion, help-center

In the current version of the [Tour page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour), the question used as a good IPS question is "When should I use Mrs. or Ms. in emails?". This is a fine, on-topic etiquette question, however, I'm afraid it might need to "what should I do" type of question (because people won't necessarily see that this is okay only because it's about etiquette).

So, I believe we should either find another suitable existing candidate or come up with a "fake" question and answers that fit easily into IPS. A question like: "How can I communicate to X that Y without the bad outcome Z?"

Here are the constraints need for the question to work:

> The posts have to be short, with at least two short answers (<=400 chars). They also shouldn't have any crazy formatting.

So, what do you think would be a good question and answers for the Tour?

<sub>Please use this question to suggest fake question and there answers.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think that a better solution would be to look for existing questions that are short and highly upvoted. I wrote [this sede query](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/969130/short-questions-with-high-scores) which looks for questions with a body length < 500 characters. The highest scoring question of the results in the query is [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-can-i-get-someone-to-say-their-first-name-without-letting-on-that-ive-forgo) which was asked during the private beta. I believe that this question would be a good candidate to demonstrate on topic questions.

The entire text of the question:

> I often face the problem of forgetting the name of a person who I last met a while ago.
>
> This can lead to an awkward situation when asking what their name is.
>
> How can I elicit them to say their name, without letting them know that I've forgotten?

Comment: If it's just a matter of 100 characters, we can increase the rules to allow for it, assuming there are good answers that fit, too. I think there are a couple of sites that have 600 characters as the max instead of 400.

Comment: @Catija Even if this specific one won't fit (I haven't check), increasing the limit for IPS would definitively be a good idea (IMO). In here, a low character number tends to mean bad question/answer, not the opposite.